# Relay - must drop-out voltage

Tags: voltage, relay

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV190Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have an output that can operate a relay at 12V but the drop out voltage is 6V. So the relay never drops out once pulled in at 12V, even though the voltage across the coil is 6V. I understand as per the datasheet, must drop-out voltage must be below 1.5V. How can I drop-out the voltage to less than 1.5V when the voltage is below say 9V?

Comment: Can you draw us a schematic, please?

Comment: What is your real circuit? You shouldn't be shorting your 12 V supply and your 6 V supply to each other. If you want your relay to open when the switch SW2  is opened, just don't connect the 6 V source to it.

Comment: it is an automotive application and I cannot figure out where 6v is coming in from.

Comment: What wires are attached to the relay coil? Where do they go?

Comment: Your schematic will not work. Closing SW2 will short the 6V and 12V supplies together.

Comment: @power_lec - Hi, You said that you "*cannot figure out where 6v is coming in from*". If I was in your situation, I would *not* be trying to design / build *any* circuit, until the source of the reported 6V has been found and understood. If you are measuring 6V with a digital multimeter, I can think of at least 2 possible causes for that to be displayed, where there really *isn't* an actual 6V source, and the situation may be more complicated than you currently think or than you describe here. Just a bit of friendly advice that ignoring such "unknowns" can sometimes lead to bigger problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allright, for a simple stable and flexible way to do it, you might consider a comparator circuit that uses a simple voltage source formed by R1 and D1 to generate a constant voltage (4.5V if you pick the right resistor and zener diode) and a resistor divider to deliver half the supply voltage to non-inverting input.

The components shoudl be sized to make the currents make more sense.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPKlNz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But you can do it more simply if you like (so you don't have to size as many components.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7khUL.png)</sup>

Here D1 and R1 form a voltage detector and turn M1 on when the voltage is greater than 9V, and off if it's less. R2 adds a little bit of hysteresis so M1 will turn on and off more completely when it switches.

The component values could probably all use some tuning, and I didn't pick that MOSFET, but the topology should do ok.